# Play WSClient Nosuchmethod error with Spark 2.2 Snapshot

Tags: apache-spark, playframework, sbt

I'm using a Play WsClient to send requests to a Spray server endpoint that fronts a Spark driver program.  The problematic call is here:

```
  def serializeDataset(requestUrl: String, recipe: Recipe): Future[(Option[String], String, Int)] = {
    ws.url(requestUrl).post(Json.toJson(recipe)).map { response =>
    val code = (response.json \ "code").as[Int]
    code match {
      case OK => ((response.json \ "uuid").asOpt[String], (response.json \ "schema").as[String], code)
      case _ => ((response.json \ "message").asOpt[String], "", code)
    }
  }
}
```

When executed, I get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.newAtomicIntegerFieldUpdater(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater;
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.<clinit>(NettyResponseFuture.java:52)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.newNettyResponseFuture(NettyRequestSender.java:311)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.newNettyRequestAndResponseFuture(NettyRequestSender.java:193)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.sendRequestWithCertainForceConnect(NettyRequestSender.java:129)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyRequestSender.sendRequest(NettyRequestSender.java:107)
    at org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClient.execute(DefaultAsyncHttpClient.java:216)
    at org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(DefaultAsyncHttpClient.java:184)
    at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClient.executeRequest(AhcWS.scala:45)
    at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSRequest$.execute(AhcWS.scala:90)
    at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSRequest$$anon$2.execute(AhcWS.scala:166)
    at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSRequest.execute(AhcWS.scala:168)
    at play.api.libs.ws.WSRequest$class.post(WS.scala:510)
    at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSRequest.post(AhcWS.scala:107)
    at webservices.DataFrameService.serializeDataset(DataFrameService.scala:36)
```

It looks like the WSClient is picking up a version of Netty that doesn't include the relevant function.

This issue occurs when I compile the application with the 2.2-SNAPSHOT version of Spark, but not when I compile with the 2.1 version.  I don't have an idea as to why this change would make a difference.  The Spark driver program is a separate project in my sbt build.

My suspicion is that this has something to do with the packaging of the application and its dependencies.  Here is what I have tried in sbt to recitify:

1. Added an explicit (`"io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.0.43.Final"`) to my dependencies
2. Added exclude statements to the spark imports like so:

   ```
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkV exclude("org.jboss.netty","netty") exclude("io.netty","netty")

   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkV exclude("org.jboss.netty","netty") exclude("io.netty","netty")

   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkV exclude("org.scalamacros", "quasiquotes") exclude("org.jboss.netty","netty") exclude("io.netty","netty")

   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkV exclude("org.scalamacros", "quasiquotes") exclude("org.jboss.netty","netty") exclude("io.netty","netty")
   ```
3. Changed the order in which the play-ws module is added to the project dependencies (moved it to the end, moved it to the beginning)

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On further review, I found that there was a lingering dependency to the Spark libraries within the Play project.  I removed this and it seems to be working.